# Robot end effector sensor query

Tags: robotic-arm, sensors

I am currently in the process of implementing a Fanuc robotic arm at our company and have just received the pneumatic gripper end effector to go on the end of the arm (which we won't have for about a week).

The end effector has come with both NPN and PNP sensors which attach into machined slots in the side of the gripper.

I have very little experience or understanding of electronics so my question is really, what is the purpose of these sensors when used in conjunction with an end effector. Do they enable and disable the gripper or is that done through controlling the air supply?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you also ask the supplier for these questions during the purchasing process? Or are they supporting you with the applications?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Adrian, but I'm afraid that questions which can only be answered by the pre-sales or technical support team for a specific manufacturer or supplier aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. *[Practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* are always welcome here though, so if you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you. Please take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions which can only be answered by the pre-sales or technical support team for a specific manufacturer or supplier aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. Please take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 0):

The PNP and NPN sensors differ in the output signal. The robot controller it is connected to must have matching inputs.

The sensor is most likely sense one of these two thing:

1. It might be used for detecting if there is an object gripped
2. It might detect the end of travel for the gripper claws.

Without documentation these are of course only guesses.